# Troubles with Google Places quota

Tags: google-places-api, billing, quota

Some weeks ago I began having API quota errors on my contact form based on Google Places:

> *"You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota,..."*

I checked the console and I saw my billing was still active with

> "Premium plan web service requests per day: unlimited".

But on the **Iam-admin** / quota page effectively it gives me

> "current usage 100%: 1".

This is affecting our production site, so I hope someone can offer some assistance.

Comment: You should contact Google maps support team via https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support